# Document in Document Library only appearing in search results where it is the only item

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search-results, sharepoint-search

so what is happening is that I have a document called
`WfD Activity Host Organisation Agreement (Individual Hosted Activity).docx`. This document appears in search results from the Home page of the SharePoint site when searching `Individual` or `Hosted` and is the only result that appears, as was expected of the search term.

The problem however, is that the document does not appear in searches where it should when there are more than 1 result. ie: When searching for `WfD` a multitude of documents show up, but not this document.

The document's title property is the same as its name (without the extension). The document also appears in the Query builder when testing the query with `wfd`.

Here is the query template I am using for search, with the site title omitted for privacy.

`{SearchBoxQuery} (Title:{SearchBoxQuery} OR Filename:{SearchBoxQuery})  SiteTitle="My Site Title" {searchTerms}`

When testing the query the query text is shown as:

`wfd (Title:wfd OR Filename:wfd)  SiteTitle="My Site Title" wfd wfd -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople`

As you can see, highlighted in yellow below, the document appears in the query builder, and the image below it shows that same search query when searching for the document live..

Looking to rectify this issue with your help, I hope I have been descriptive enough!

[image: Query Builder Screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Search Query Tool to check if you can get the results when set the Trim Duplicate option to disable.

If so, you need to query with more unique text to get the result.

Or there is a workaround to search in the search center to edit the search result web part to group the refiner by documentsignature, more information check the blog below: [Search Results and Duplicate Detection in SharePoint Online](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ravipriya_de_alwis/2014/11/15/search-results-and-duplicate-detection-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! The document signatures seem to be duplicated and is causing issues as you suggested. Cheers!